# "/vagrant" shared folder does not exist

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

When I create a virtual machine through vagrant, and ssh into the machine the "/vagrant" folder does not exist.

## Currently Running the following

- Host OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Virtualbox: Version 5.0.18_Ubuntu r106667
- Guest Additions: 5.0.18
- Vagrant Version: 1.8.1
- Vagrant vb-guest plugin with the Vagrant 1.8.1 plugin patch from: https://github.com/tobwilk/vagrant-plugin-v1.8.1-fix

*Note there is no mention of "Mounting Shared Folders" when the machine boots up.*
The Vagrantfile is the standard file created from "vagrant init".

Any help on to why this may be happening would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 (vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64), but 14.04 works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make sure that in your Vagrantfile you dont have something

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
```

Also if you dont, force the default `/vagrant` folder to be shared

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
```

when booting your VM, you should have logs like

```
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/.....path to project directory
```

If nothing works, 2 things you can explore:

- is sync_folder working with another folder definition ?
- boot with debug option `vagrant up --debug` to see whats happening after `Mounting shared folders`

Comment: Synced folders **were not** initially disabled. Adding the `config.vm.synced_folder ".","/vagrant"` worked. However, that seems like a bit of a workaround. Is that not supposed to be default behavior?

Comment: it could be because of a 1) global vagrantfile or the 2) box vagrantfile - to check create a VM from another box (like `ubuntu/wily64` for example) and see if `/vagrant` is set; if it works it means your current box has Vagrantfile which deactivate the sync folder. If the folder is still disabled it could be because it is disabled in a global vagrantfile

Comment: ok then it might be an issue with the previous box, check if you have a file ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/<yourboxwithissue>/0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile ? if you do check content of the file to see if you have a disable sync folder

Comment: None of these worked for me. Vagrant refuses to mount the host directory to `/vagrant`.

Comment: @Distortum which box do you have ?

Comment: @FredericHenri never mind. It was caused by the box not having my ssh public key. Without ssh authentication, there’s no file sync.